# How to redirect outgoing network connections?

Tags: socket, redirection, tunneling

I was wondering how would I redirect outgoing connections from all applications to a certain proxy or something like that without having to hook winsock functions on windows. I noticed Proxifier is able to do that without installing any drivers of some sort and I doubt it hooks the connect function on all running processes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking HTTP connections, that is doable with the right network-level gear without having any local client changes. It's called an Intercept Proxy, and [squid](/questions/tagged/squid), among other packages, can handle just that. Some Cisco gear has a method of forcing all HTTP connections to something like Squid without the cache-box having to be on a router. This leverages the Web Cache Control Protocol.